# Carrierwave Temporary File Without Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I need to be able to attach a file to a mail (using Mailer) for a recently uploaded file which is not linked to any Model.

In the code that goes for the upload form:

```
<%= form_for(:mail, :url => {:action => 'send_mail'}, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<table summary="send_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Attachment</th>
    <td><%= f.file_field(:attachment) %><a id="attachment"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= submit_tag "Send!" %>
```

Now, what I am looking into doing in the send_mail action is something like:

```
MyMailer.send_mail(params[:mail][:attachment]).deliver
```

with params[:mail][:attachment] being the path to the temp file uploaded with the form. How can one do that?

This also implies another question: Should I manually delete the file from the temp once the mail is sent? If yes, how?

Comment: Finally nailed it: `unless (params[:mail][:attachment]).nil?
      uploader = AttachmentUploader.new
      uploader.cache!(params[:mail][:attachment])
      @file_name = uploader.filename
      @file_data = uploader.file.read()
    end` and then `MyMailer.send_mail(@file_name,@file_data)`

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

Finally nailed it:

```
unless (params[:mail][:attachment]).nil?
  uploader = AttachmentUploader.new
  uploader.cache!(params[:mail][:attachment])
  @file_name = uploader.filename
  @file_data = uploader.file.read()
end
```

and then

```
MyMailer.send_mail(@file_name,@file_data)
```

~ answer per [user1563325](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563325/user1563325)

Comment: This worked for me! Do you know how I would use the same method for multiple files @DreadPirateShawn? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that for the scenario described here, maybe you don't need CarrierWave for such a temporary upload situation. When uploading using `file_field`, Rails saves it into a [Tempfile](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Tempfile.html), whose path you can access like this:

```
params[:mail][:attachment].path
```

These files are deleted automatically so you shouldn't need to worry about them, as the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) explain:

> Uploaded files are temporary files whose lifespan is one request. When the object is finalized Ruby unlinks the file, so there is no need to clean them with a separate maintenance task.